# How do I avoid Ansible dependency on specific Python version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, uri

I'm porting some playbooks from Python 2 to Python 3. In this, a play was invoking the URI module and it was making a confusing invocation directly to /usr/bin/python: (with -vvv)

```
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist- 
packages/ansible/modules/net_tools/basics/uri.py
<10.216.247.143> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<10.216.247.143> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python && sleep 0'
```

I'm trying to execute this playbook in an environment without python 2 installed, therefore this fails. How do I make the URI module use python3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which python is invoked is controlled in two places. The first is ansible.cfg:

`ansible_python_interpreter = /usr/bin/python`

That set the local python executable environment to /usr/bin/python. Additionally, I was able to set the python executable on the managed nodes through an inventory variable:

`[managers:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3`